# How to allow user to change font size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a google docs like app, and I want the user to be able to select the text, and then change the size to whatever they want. I tried to use variables but it didn't work so I am not sure what to do. Is there any way to allow the user to change the font size and if so how?

Here is the code for the app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="bold" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);">
      
    </button>

    <button class="italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);">
      
    </button>

    <button
      class="underline"
      onclick="document.execCommand('underline',false,null);"
    >
      U̲
    </button>

    <input
      type="color"
      class="color-picker"
      id="colorPicker"
      oninput="changeColorText(this.value);"
    />
    <label>Select color</label>

    <button id="highlight"><mark>Highlight</mark></button>

    <fieldset class="userInput" contenteditable="true"></fieldset>

    <script>
      var boldBtn = document.querySelector(".bold");
      var italicBtn = document.querySelector(".italic");
      var underlineBtn = document.querySelector(".underline");
      var colorPicker = document.querySelector(".color-picker");
      var highlightBtn = document.querySelector("#highlight");

      boldBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        boldBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
      });

      italicBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        italicBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
      });

      underlineBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        underlineBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
      });

      highlightBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        highlightBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
      });

      const changeColorText = (color) => {
        document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, true);
        document.execCommand("foreColor", false, color);
      };

      document
        .getElementById("highlight")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
          var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
            span = document.createElement("span");

          span.className = "highlight";
          span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
          range.insertNode(span);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I tried to use variables...` ? javascript variables or css variables ?

Comment: @MisterJojo css variables

Comment: and did you use `em` or `rem` units ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the output you want. Also, don't use `document.execCommand`, it has been deprecated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Editor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <button class="bold" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);">
          
        </button>
    
        <button class="italic" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);">
          
        </button>
    
        <button
          class="underline"
          onclick="document.execCommand('underline',false,null);"
        >
          U̲
        </button>
    
        <input
          type="color"
          class="color-picker"
          id="colorPicker"
          oninput="changeColorText(this.value);"
        />
        <label>Select color</label>
    
        <button id="highlight"><mark>Highlight</mark></button>
        <input
          type="number"
          class="font-size"
          id="fontSize"
     
        />
        <label>Select Font Size</label>
        <fieldset class="userInput" contenteditable="true"></fieldset>
    
        <script>
          var boldBtn = document.querySelector(".bold");
          var italicBtn = document.querySelector(".italic");
          var underlineBtn = document.querySelector(".underline");
          var colorPicker = document.querySelector(".color-picker");
          var fontSize = document.querySelector("#fontSize");
          var highlightBtn = document.querySelector("#highlight");
          var userInput = document.querySelector('.userInput');
          boldBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            boldBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
          });
    
          italicBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            italicBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
          });
    
          underlineBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            underlineBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
          });
    
          highlightBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            highlightBtn.classList.toggle("inUse");
          });
    
          const changeColorText = (color) => {
            document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, true);
            document.execCommand("foreColor", false, color);
          };
    
          fontSize.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
          
          function updateValue(e) {
            
        userInput.style.fontSize = `${e.target.value}px`;
    
    }
          
          document
            .getElementById("highlight")
            .addEventListener("click", function () {
              var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
                span = document.createElement("span");
    
              span.className = "highlight";
              span.appendChild(range.extractContents());
              range.insertNode(span);
            });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your HTML:

```
<button class="font-smaller">-</button>
<button class="font-bigger">+</button>
```

Add this to your JS:

```
const fontSmaller = document.querySelector(".font-smaller");
const fontBigger = document.querySelector(".font-bigger");
let fontSize = 15.5; // play with this number if needed

fontSmaller.addEventListener("click", () => {
 document.querySelector(".userInput").style.fontSize = `${fontSize--}px`;
});

fontBigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
 document.querySelector(".userInput").style.fontSize = `${fontSize++}px`;
});
```

Change as needed. This will change the size of the whole text.

Comment: Will this make the selected text change?

Comment: This will change the font size for the entire DOM element, not the user-selected text range.

Comment: Is there a way to make it just the selected text?

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin You may want to change the value of font-size for the root element which spreads font-size through css inheritance to children.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it like this.

```js
// Increase/descrease font size
$('#increasetext').click(function() {
  curSize = parseInt($('#content').css('font-size')) + 2;
  if (curSize <= 32)
    $('#content').css('font-size', curSize);
});

$('#resettext').click(function() {
  if (curSize != 18)
    $('#content').css('font-size', 18);
});

$('#decreasetext').click(function() {
  curSize = parseInt($('#content').css('font-size')) - 2;
  if (curSize >= 14)
    $('#content').css('font-size', curSize);
});
```

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}


/* text-controls */

button {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0 0.3125em;
  padding: 0 0.3125em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

button#increasetext {
  font-size: 1.50em;
}

button#resettext {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

button#decreasetext {
  font-size: 1.125em;
}

.textcontrols {
  padding: 0.625em 0;
  background: #ccc;
}


/* content */

#content {
  margin: 3em 0;
  text-align: left;
}


/* demo container */

#container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2%;
}

#description {
  margin-bottom: 1.25em;
  text-align: left;
}

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
  #container {
    width: 700px;
  }
  button {
    margin: 0 0.625em;
    padding: 0 0.625em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">
      Allow Users to Change Font Size
    </h1>

    <p>Click the buttons to see it in action</p>
    <div class="textcontrols">
      <button role="button" id="decreasetext" <span>smaller</span>
            </button>
      <button role="button" id="resettext">
                <span>normal</span>
            </button>
      <button role="button" id="increasetext">
                <span>bigger</span>
            </button>
    </div>
    <!--/.textcontrols-->
  </header>
  <main id="content" role="main">
    <div id="description">
      <h2>Allow users to resize text on the page via button controls.</h2>
      <p>In this instance, users can decrease text, increase text, or reset it back to normal.</p>
      <h2>Set default text size with CSS</h2>
      <p>The default text size must be set using an internal stylesheet in the header of your page. In this case: <code>font-size: 1.125em</code> (aka, 18px).</p>
      <h2>Set the controls with JavaScript</h2>
      <p>Then we set the resize controls with JavaScript. In this example, we're resizing all text within the div with an id of "content".</p>
      <p>The controls check the current text size, and then changes it (or not) accordingly.</p>
    </div>
    <!--/#description-->
  </main>
  <!--/#content-->
</div>
<!--/#container-->
```

Comment: This changes the font size for the entire element, not the user selected text range.